# Arduino circuit not responding

Tags: c++, serialization, arduino, robotics

I am trying to control a car/wheeled robot basically with this code. The problem here is that if I send signals faster than 0.9 seconds, the Arduino cannot process it. Is there any way to fix it?

(I have checked the serial monitor from a different computer and it shows the Arduino still receives the signal but it doesn't provide the output to my motor controller).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include <Servo.h>

//Using mega 2560 and sabertooth 2x12 dip switch 010111

int onevar;
int twovar;
Servo myservo;
Servo myservo2;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:s
  pinMode(servo1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(servo2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(servo1);
  myservo2.attach(servo2);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
  //works for 10ms 0.9s need to figure out
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  // Receive up to 7 bytes
  if (Serial.available()>0) {
    // Wait for characters
    onevar = Serial.parseInt();
    twovar = Serial.parseInt();
    //number = atoi(buffer);
    Serial.println(onevar);
    Serial.println(twovar);
    /*  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
     number = Serial.read()-'0'; // read the incoming byte:
     Serial.print(number);
    */
    myservo.write(onevar);
    // 93 is stop backward and forward is scalable range 25 to 155
    myservo2.write(twovar);
    //93 is no steering 30 to 160
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't show what calls `loop` which isn't a loop anyway. Aside: move global variables to be local variables within the function they relate to, wherever possible.

Comment: @WeatherVane - `setup()` and `loop()` are called from a hidden `main()` on Arduino. `main()` keeps calling loop over and over.

Comment: I don't know how the timeout works here (per char or per message), but 9600 baud can receive only one char per millisecond. Your timeout is 10 milliseconds, which is a bit tight to receive two number fields as text.

Comment: There also needs to be some *point* to having a timeout. What action might be impeded if nothing is received? What action do you take when a timeout is generated?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try:

```
  Serial.begin(9600);
```

Try setting the baud rate higher (on both ends).

```
  Serial.println(onevar);
  Serial.println(twovar);
```

Comment those out for some testing.

```
Servo myservo;
Servo myservo2;
```

2 servos and 1 serial port. It could happen that there is a conflict with the timers (multiple libraries using/setting the same timer). Does it work with 1 servo?

Comment: Tried changing the baud-rate. No notable change was observed. Tried using one servo, didn't improve.

Comment: Also if its possible can you let me know any other methods of getting two numbers from a signal that is faster. For this one I am sending signals like "120a90" to get onevar=120 and twovar=90.

Comment: @PrangonDeySwachha - To send and receive values faster, Serial.write() and Serial.readBytes() would be better (using binary data directly). You could use readBytes to read in a 16-bit number without the need to parse. But they need to come in as binary as well then.